# C function pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
static void increment(long long *n){
  (*n)++;
}

struct test{
  void (*work_fn)(long long *);
};

struct test t1;

t1.work_fn = increment;
```

How do I actually call the function now? t1.work_fn(&n) ?

Comment: Yes, a function pointer acts like a regular function. A snobby answer would be: Why don't you try it and find out? :)

Comment: Have you tried it? what was the result?  Really, nothing wrong with writing code, running it, testing it, watching it in the debugger.

Comment: @abelenky: There is, if you're unsure whether you're relying on undefined behaviour, or non-standard language extensions, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I actually call the function now? `t1.work_fn(&n)` ?

That'll work just fine.

Function pointers don't need to be explicitly dereferenced. This is because even when calling a function normally (using the actual name of the function), you're really calling it through the pointer to the function.  C99 6.5.22 "Function calls" says (emphasis mine):

> The expression that denotes the called function (footnote 77) **shall have type pointer to function** returning void or returning an object type other than an array type

Footnote 77:

> Most often, this is the result of converting an identifier that is a function designator.

Note that you still *can* dereference the function pointer (or a normal function name - though I think you'd cause much confusion doing so) to call a function because C99 6.5.3.2/4 "Address and indirection operators" says:

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator

So all of these will end up doing the same thing (though the compiler might not be able to optimize the calls-through `t1.work_fn` as well):

```
t1.work_fn(&n);
(*t1.work_fn)(&n);

increment(&n);
(*increment)(&n);
```

Comment: In fact, at the source code level in value context one can dereference a function [pointer] as many times as one wants. A function `foo` can be called as `foo()` or as `(*foo)()` or as `(*******foo)()` with identical behavior in all these cases.

Comment: @Andrey: I was just about to add that comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can call it as `t1.work_fn(&n)` or as `(*t1.work_fn)(&n)`, whichever you prefer.

Symmetrically, when assigning the pointer you can do either `t1.work_fn = increment` or `t1.work_fn = &increment`. Again, it is a matter of personal coding style.

One can probably argue that for the sake of consistency one should stick to either "minimalistic" style

```
t1.work_fn = increment;
t1.work_fn(&n);
```

or to a "maximalistic" style

```
t1.work_fn = &increment;
(*t1.work_fn)(&n);
```

but not a mix of the two, so that we can have well-defined holy wars between two distinctive camps instead of four.

P.S. Of course, the "minimalistic" style is the only proper one. And one must crack eggs on the pointy end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how to call it. Function names and variables containing function pointers are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Hm... my memory says different. But since the assignment works, that makes sense. Did that already work this way in 1990? Or did that change with one of the latest releases of C?

Comment: @Aaron: I noticed that. I'm going to go find a real reference, so it's not just I remember/you remember.

Comment: In value context (like when one's making a call), they do act as "the same thing". In object context they are not the same, of course. For example, applying the unary `&` to a function and to a pointer will produce completely different results. The situation is similar to arrays: they often act like pointers, but in general they are not.

Comment: @AndreyT: Thanks for clearing that up. I had just found C99 §6.5.2.2.

Comment: @Aaron - it worked this way in 1990. It has worked this way since at least K&R 1 (1978).