# In C, what is the difference between `&function` and `function` when passed as arguments?

Tags: c, function, functional-programming, operators

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (* proto_1)();
typedef void proto_2();

void my_function(int j){
    printf("hello from function. I got %d.\n",j);
}

void call_arg_1(proto_1 arg){
    arg(5);
}
void call_arg_2(proto_2 arg){
    arg(5);
}
void main(){
    call_arg_1(&my_function);
    call_arg_1(my_function);
    call_arg_2(&my_function);
    call_arg_2(my_function);
}
```

Running this I get the following:

```
> tcc -run try.c
hello from function. I got 5.
hello from function. I got 5.
hello from function. I got 5.
hello from function. I got 5.
```

My two questions are:

- What is the difference between a function prototype defined with `(* proto)` and one defined without?
- What is the difference between calling a function with the reference operator (`&`) and without?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. Not posting as an answer because I'm not really sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function pointers in C - address operator "unnecessary"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258422/function-pointers-in-c-address-operator-unnecessary)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no difference. For evidence see the [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (section 6.7.5.3.8).

"A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to
function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1."

Comment: Thanks for the reference Nick! (It's section 6.7.**5**.3.8, by the way.) So it's essentially a language special case?

Comment: @brice - thanks I've edited. Yes a special case. The function pointer one makes more sense for being consistent with the rest of the language, but I guess they added the other case for readability

Comment: The corollary to this is that you can explicitly dereference function names or function pointers and arbitrary number of times (zero, one or more) and always get the same result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834520/c-function-pointers/5834568#5834568

Comment: this is only half of the truth: 6.7.5.3.8 is only concerned with the type declarations; the implicit conversion of function designators to function pointers is covered by section 6.3.2.1

Answer (score 8):

there is no difference between `&function` and `function` when passing as arguement

however there is a difference between your typedefs. I do not know the official explanation, i.e what exactly the difference, but from what i remember

```
typedef void (*name1)(void);
```

and

```
typedef void(name2)(void);
```

are different:

name1 is a pointer to a function that takes no paramter and returns nothing

name2 is a function that takes no paramter and returns nothing

you can test it by compiling:

```
typedef void (*pointer)(void);
typedef void (function)(void);

void foo(void){}

int main()
{
    pointer p;
    function f;

    p = foo; //compiles
    p();

    f = foo; //does not compile
    f();
}
```

again, i am not the right person to explain exact reason of this behavior but i believe if you take a look at standards you will find the explanation somewhere there

Comment: I guess you could already feel this one coming: *... when passing as arguement* - what's the difference otherwise, then?  :-)

Comment: hehe :) not sure but as far as i know totally the same. why both of them exist? i don't know. i think it is just like 
int & const r; 
and 
int &r;
of c++

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the typedefs. That makes sense and follows the usual semantics.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference between &function and function - they're both addresses.  You can see this by printing them both:

```
function bar(); 

.... 
printf("addr bar is 0x%d\n", &bar);
printf("bar is 0x%d\n", bar);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the "you can see this by..." is wrong. For an array, `array` and `&array` are not remotely the same (they have *very* different types!) but printing their addresses with `printf` will show the same thing (assuming you correctly use `%p` rather than `%d` and cast to `void *`). BTW there is no way to print function pointers with `printf` since C completely lacks any conversion from a function pointer type to `void *` or any integer types.

Comment: The statement "there is no way to print function pointers" is not true.  You can run the code I pasted in above (I did so).

Comment: That code invokes undefined behavior by passing mismatching types to `printf`. If it does what you expected, that just means you got unlucky, i.e. the bug in your code went undetected.

Comment: By the way, printing an `0x` before a decimal number is rather perverse... :-)

Comment: Also, while it is true that in the C language array and &array are not the same, they compile to the same value: an address.  I think in the spirit of the OP's question, it is helpful to point this out.

Comment: `0x%x` would not fix it. You should use `%p` (pointer), but this only works if the argument is cast to `void *`. For function pointer types, the only way to print them is to access the representation and print it a byte at a time.

Comment: It's what I checked too before asking (using `%p` as suggested though), but as R said, passing a `int` and a `&int` have very different meanings. Is this essentially a special case for function parameters?

Comment: @R - I can use 0x%p without casting - gcc 4.2.1 on MacOS.

Comment: @Scott - ...and I can compile and run `x = x++ * ++x`, but it's still undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is only stylistic. You have the same scenario when using function pointers:

```
void func (void);
```

...

```
void(*func_ptr)(void) = func;

func_ptr();    // call func
(*func_ptr)(); // call func

printf("%d\n", ptr); 
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

There are some who say that the (*func_ptr)() syntax is to prefer, to make it clear that the function call is done through a function pointer. Others believe that the style with the * is clearer.

As usual, there are likely no scientific studies proving that either form is better than the other, so just pick one style and stick to it.