# When do we need & when passing a function?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I found these work types of code:

```
hash_init.key       = &hash_key_lc;
```

And

```
ls->handler = init_connection;
```

Here both `hash_key_lc` and `init_connection` are functions,but one is with `&` the other not,why?

**UPDATE**

so they are the same thing,but what's the rational??

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, what is the difference between `&function` and `function` when passed as arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293403/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-function-when-passed-as-ar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reference/deference` on a `function` is treated as a language special case in `c`,as `function` deserves this kind of special case ,it can't be passed by a certain `value`,you can only pass it by `address/reference`.

Answer (score 2):

This is identical to the following question:
[In C, what is the difference between `&function` and `function` when passed as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293403/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-function-when-passed-as-ar)

The accepted answer there:

> There is no difference. For evidence
>   see the [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (section
>   6.7.5.3.8).
>
> "A declaration of a parameter as
>   ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1."

Comment: @Mike,but this isn't consistent,how can a pointer (`*`) and a pointer to pointer (`**`) be no difference?

Comment: Post duplicates as comments, not answers, and vote to close if you have enough rep. -1

Comment: @new_perl - It's not `void (*)(void)` (pointer to function) and `void(**)(void)` (pointer to pointer to function), it's `void(void)` (function) and `void (*)(void)`. Function is converted to pointer to function when passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Chris Lutz ,don't you think this is making it inconsistent in syntax? I don't see the rational behind this.

Comment: @new_perl - Perhaps. The rationale probably is that you clearly can't pass a function by value (what is `sizeof(void (void))` supposed to be?) but it's a valid type and valid declaration, so why not do something with it? I personally prefer seeing `pass(func)` to `pass(&func)`.

Comment: the quoted section only applies to parameter declarations - the actual conversion is covered by C99 6.3.2.1 §4

Comment: @compile-fan - That is (one if the worst IMHO) nonstandard GCC extensions. `sizeof` on function and `void` types is undefined or worse.

Answer (score 1):

See C99 section 6.3.2.1, §4:

> A *function designator* is an
>   expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the
>   `sizeof` operator or the unary `&`
>   operator, a function designator with
>   type ‘‘function returning *type*’’ is
>   converted to an expression that has
>   type ‘‘pointer to function returning
>   *type*’’.

Thus, if `foo` is a function, the expressions `foo` and `&foo` are mostly interchangeable, in particular

```
foo == &foo
```

This is similar to how expressions with array type are implicitly converted to expressions with pointer type. Also, if `fp` is a function pointer, you can call it with or without dereferencing, ie the expressions

```
(*fp)(42)
```

and

```
fp(42)
```

are equivalent. Function calls are actually defined in terms of function pointers (section 6.5.2.2 §1) and not function designators, ie as far as language semantics go, `*fp` in the first example will implicitly converted back to `fp` before the parens are applied.