# Why assignment to the function type gives an error?

Tags: c++, function

I'm reading [this answer - about function name as pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293420/7813604), in the post the author said why it's not compiled is not known, which is my question, I want to know why. (Please don't annoy the author or I will angry, thanks.)

So what's the way to assign something to `f`?

This is the code directly copied from there:

```
typedef void (*pointer)(void);
typedef void (function)(void);

void foo(void){}

int main()
{
    pointer p;
    function f;

    p = foo; //compiles
    p();

    f = foo; //does not compile
    f();
}
```

The error message is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘void()’ to ‘function {aka void()}’ in assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `function` is typedefed as a function type, when you declare a "variable" of type `function`, it actually declares a function, not a variable. Functions can't be assigned to, so this behaviour makes perfect sense.