# C pthread formatting

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm not sure if this is something GCC is correcting during compilation, but I can't find a definite answer as to which call is correct for `pthread_create`.  I've seen both formats used in tutorials, however it seems that one should fail (unless the compiler is doing something behind the scenes to put it in the right format):

```
pthread_create (&thread, NULL, thread_func, (void *) var);
```

**OR**

```
pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &thread_func, (void *) var);
```

Notice the first call passes in the function pointer, whereas the second passes in the address to the function pointer.  It seems like one should break, but both compile and execute correctly.

**thread_func def:**

```
void *thread_func (void *var);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, what is the difference between \`&function\` and \`function\` when passed as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293403/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-function-when-passed-as-a)

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, thread_func is the same.  I'll update the post to include this

Comment: @eukaryota Thank you!  This is a duplicate and can be marked as such.  I thought this was specific to pthreads and was having difficulty finding an answer.  Turns out I could have broadened my search and come across the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will decay to a function pointer hence both works the same.