# For function pointer "fptr",why is value of "fptr" and *fptr same?What *fptr even mean?I only knew (*fptr)() or fptr()

Tags: c, function-pointers

Why is a `function pointer` behaving like an `array pointer` as far as this behavior goes?I mean, let's begin with the case of an array `list[]` where we'll consider `&list` and `list`.

```
 char name[5]= "Eric",(*aptr)[5]=&name;
 printf("%p,%p",*aptr,name); //BOTH ARE NUMERICALLY SAME
```

and we can refer to array elements also as `(*aptr)[1]`,`(*aptr)[2]`, etc.I understand what's going on here.

But why is the same working for functions?After all a "function" as such is not a contiguous memory block of similar elements as an array is.Consider this.

Suppose `fptr` is a function pointer as in my program.Why does `fptr` and `*fptr` give the same value when printed?What does `*fptr` even mean?I only knew that we can invoke a function using its pointer as `(*fptr)()` or as `fptr()`,but what is `*fptr` alone then?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(){};

int main(void)
{
void (*fptr)()=foo;
printf("%p,%p",fptr,*fptr);

}
```

**Result-**  `00401318  00401318`

Comment: A function is implicitly convertible to a function pointer, and if you dereference a function, it gets converted to a function pointer again. And again. And again... You can also do `****************fptr` without problems.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834568/12711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pointer is to point to a memory location. A function is in memory and has a starting address. You can very well dereference the function name(which is a pointer) to obtain the function at that address.

From, Stephen Prata "*Cpp Primer Plus*"

---

> History Versus Logic Holy syntax!

---

> How can pf and (*pf) be equivalent?
>   **One school** of thought maintains that because pf is a pointer to a
>   function, *pf is a function; hence, you should use (*pf)() as a
>   function call. A **second school** maintains that because the name of a
>   function is a pointer to that function, a pointer to that function
>   should act like the name of a function; hence you should use pf() as a
>   function call. C++ takes the compromise view that both forms are
>   correct, or at least can be allowed, even though they are logically
>   inconsistent with each other. Before you judge that compromise too
>   harshly, reflect that the ability to hold views that are not logically
>   self-consistent is a hallmark of the human mental process.